# Character Arithmetic --- Base 8 vs Base 10

Tags: java, unicode, character, ascii, character-properties

When doing character arithmetic is it a rule that you perform the calculations in base 10 or base 8? My book says 'A' = 101 in base 8  or 65 base 10 but when I insert the character values in base 8 into an example my book gives about illustrating this point i get some funny results. The code below is an example in my book for  a Ceaser Cipher that tries to find the new character. If I try to convert 'Y' and shift 8 spots to find a new character and if ch = 'Y' and n = 8 I'm expecting to get character 'G'.

```
ch = (char)('A' + (Character.toUpperCase(ch) - 'A' + n) % 26);
```

the math works out to 
 65 + (89  - 65 + 8) % 26 = 71  (base 10) 
                      101 + (131 - 101 + 8) % 26 = 113 (base 8)

If i convert the 71 (base 10) back into base 8, I'll get 107 which is character 'G' which is the correct character. My question is why I can't perform character arithmetic in base 8? 113 is character 'K' which is the wrong character.  Is the rule when doing character arithmetic to convert all the values into base 10 and then convert them back into base 8?

Comment: I'm really confused. Why do you want to deal with octal? Aside from that ... where's your code that's doing the math in base8?

Comment: @BrianRoach isn't the values of 'A' in base 8? So when you insert the numbers into the code in my book don't you have to use base 8 numbers? Or am I way off?

Comment: No. Everything is base10 by default. 'A' == 65 (at least if you're using a charset that preserves US-ASCII values). Your code is `(65 + (<some_val> - 65 + n) % 26)`

Comment: @JessicaM., a numeric value isn't *in* any base.  A number is what it is.  Only a string representation of a number has a base.

Comment: @MikeSamuel technically, it's base2 :-D I was trying to come up with better words and failing. It's better to say textual *Output* of values in Java is base10 by default.

Comment: @BrianRoach, I don't think that's right.  That a set of stable voltages in a register can forward to a binary-adder's input lines does not mean that the number represented by the voltages in the register *is* binary.  A value is an abstract semantically-significant concept that can be represented in many ways, but which is distinct from its representation.

Comment: @JessicaM.: No, nothing is in base 8 by default.  Almost nothing you'll ever need to do, including working with characters, is in base 8.  Base 8 is entirely a red herring here: forget everything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computers store values in memory. Everything else is a convenience for our dumb human brains (and eyes). By default, in Java any *textual output* of those values is going to be in base10 (decimal).

`A` is 65 in base10, and 101 in base8 (provided we're talking about a character set that preserves US-ASCII values).

When talking about *literals* in Java, by default they are interpreted as base10. To use an octal literal, you need to precede it by a `0`:

```
int a1 = 65;   // literals are by default base10
int a2 = 0101; // an octal literal in Java is preceded by a 0
int a3 = 'A';
System.out.println(a1 == a2 && a2 == a3);
```

The above will output `true`.

If you want to in your example, you can set `n` via an octal literal or parse an octal `String` to an int, you get the result you expect:

```
int n = 010; // octal literal equal to decimal 8
int a = 'A' + ('Y' - 'A' + n) % 26;
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(Integer.toOctalString(a));
```

outputs:

> 71
>   107

You could also parse an octal `String` for `n`:

```
int n = Integer.valueOf("010", 8);
```

The issue you're really facing here is trying to do base8 math, but performing *base10* arithmetic (and you left `n` as decimal `8`):

```
int o = 101 + (131 - 101 + 8) % 26;
System.out.println(o);
System.out.println(Integer.toOctalString(o));
```

Java interprets those literals as base10 representations, and that most certainly will result in:

> 113
>   161

On the other hand, were you to use octal literals and do the same...

```
int o = 0101 + (0131 - 0101 + 010) % 26;
System.out.println(o);
System.out.println(Integer.toOctalString(o));
```

Outputs:

> 71
>   107

Comment: Thank you very very much. I don't know why i got so confused.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* your problem is that the modulo function cannot use "26" in both cases -- 26(base 8) is 22 decimal; there are 32(base 8) characters in the English alphabet.  Try your base 8 calculations with

```
... % 32(base 8)
```

instead of with 26(base 8).

Comment: That was exactly the problem. It took me a while to grasp such a simple concept.